# Raw HTML passed with dangerouslySetInnerHTML React & Electron "lowercased"

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm stumbling through a bit of React w/ [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) that uses [react-photonkit](http://react-photonkit.github.io/#/) which is adding some headwind. I'm trying to create a dynamic horizontal menu in the photon `header` based on the primary side menu so as the primary changes, it will trigger the horizontal choices to update.

To try and get a feel for how I might approach this, I was trying to do something like:

```
function dynHeader() {
    return { __html: '<ButtonGroup> <Button glyph=\'home\' /> </ButtonGroup>' };
}

...
....render() {
      return (
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={dynHeader()} />
      )
    };
```

It appears the rendered html is all lowercase which breaks the photon integration.

[image]

If anyone has any thoughts on how I might address this I'd appreciate some help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible this way.

The Reason is that you are adding:

```
<ButtonGroup> <Button glyph=\'home\' /> </ButtonGroup>
```

at run time,which will be executed as a simple HTML tag and will not be processed by React. It will always print this way whatever you do.

What you can try is, create a dynamic component in which a user can change Simple text and class names. You can add multiple DOMS as per user inputs.

[Dynamic child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651583/dynamically-add-child-components-in-react)