# React Native - how to add form card in a list of card on Button press

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am creating an Add button and cards every one of them contain three inputs. 
i want on user click a new MultiCityCard added and how to manage their states like the screen shot.

[image]

```
<View style={{}}>
    <MultiCityCard title="Flight 1" />
    <MultiCityCard title="Flignt 2" />
    <Button
      icon={{
        name: 'plus',
        size: 20,
        color: 'white',
        type: 'entypo',
      }}
      title="Add another flight"
      containerStyle={{ padding: 20 }}
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: Hello, you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651583/dynamically-add-child-components-in-react

However, you might need to lift up your state

Comment: @mliki brother can you use FlatList for such a scenario! I think that would be very much fine in a listing scenario!  want me to give an example on that one?

Comment: @Rizwanatta sorry i couldn't understant your idea by using a flatList. can you give an exemple?

Answer (score 2):

Take your data inside array.
For example

```
data: [
  {
   from: '',
   to: '',
  }
]
```

and when you click on add, push new element to this array. for example

```
this.setState({ data: [{ from: '', to: ''},...this.state.data]})
```

Then you can edit or view the data according to index.
For example

```
data.map((item, index) => <Button onPress={() => {
// here you have access to the index 
} }
/>);
```

If you want more detailed example, I posted a snack for you 
https://snack.expo.io/@azaabudeen/Y2FyZW

Comment: yeah i get the idea but i will appreciate a detailed example.

Comment: Sure. Let me give you an example via snack